# Show that if $\gcd(a, b) = d$ and $\gcd(a, c) = f$ then $\gcd(a, bc) = \gcd(a, df)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is my solution:

Let $m = \gcd(a, bc), n = \gcd(a, df)$. Since $d|b , f|c$ so   $b = kd, c = k'f$ $\Rightarrow  bc = kk'df \Rightarrow df|bc$
$n|a, n|df, df|bc \Rightarrow n|bc  \Rightarrow n|\gcd(a,bc) \Rightarrow n|m$

But I can't go on any more to show $m|n$!! Please help me complete the solution.

Comment: Note that  $m=\gcd(a,bc)$ divides $\gcd(a,b)* \gcd(a,c)=df$. [Check this for a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492022/does-gcda-bc-divides-gcda-b-gcda-c/1492083#1492083).

Comment: @Nizar Thank you,that was so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

if $m|bc$ then there exist $m'$ and $m''$ with $m = m'm''$ such that $m'|b$ and $m''|c$. Since $m = m'm''|a$ we know that $m'|a$ and $m''|a$. Hence $m'|\gcd(a,b) = d$ and $m''|\gcd(a,c) = f$, so $m = m'm''|df$ and $m|\gcd(a, df) = n$.