# If $p$ is a prime number, then $(p-1)!$ is not divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can understand that since $p$ is prime, it does not have factors (apart from $1$). Since, $(p-1)!$ does not contain any factor of $p$ or $p$ itself, $p$ cannot divide $(p-1)!$

But I am unable to write a formal proof of it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are two common definitions of "prime numbers".  One is the property you've referenced.  The other is "$p>1$ is prime if and only if for every $a,b$, $p \mid ab$ implies $p \mid a$ or $p\mid b$."  That one gives you a nice, simple proof.

Comment: If you prefer not to change your definition of a prime, you can refer to Brian Moehring's result above as Euclid's lemma.

Comment: @Brian , I think the Euclid's lemma would be good to solve the problem ! Thanks !

Comment: Wilson s Theorem.

Comment: To add on to that, there is a nice theorem called Wilson's Theorem that directly proves this result, and the theorem states that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (mod p)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, @dxiv! I read the thing too fast, I guess; I don't know what I was thinking. It's very early in the morning here.

Comment: I wish people were more mindful before casting all those down/close votes. The OP asked a clear and honest question, with all the context and own work they could show for it. Yes, some may deem it a naive question, but that's not a reason to dismiss it offhand on MSE last I checked.

Comment: It's an immediate consequence of Euclid's Lemma: $p\mid 2\cdot 3\cdots p-1\Rightarrow p\mid 2\,$ or $\,p\mid 3\,$ or $\ldots p\mid p-1,\,$ which is false since $p\mid k>0\Rightarrow p\le k\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that for a prime number p, and a positive interger $i<p$, we have $gcd(i,p)=1$.

So $gcd(i,p)=1, i=1,2,...,p-1$.

Multiply them all, we have $gcd((p-1)!,p)∣gcd(1,p)⋅gcd(2,p)⋅⋅⋅gcd(p-1,p)$

So $gcd((p-1)!,p)=1$, and p is a prime number. Done!

(In fact, by Wilson's Theorem, we know that for a prime number n>1, ${\displaystyle (n-1)!\ \equiv \;-1{\pmod {n}}}$.)

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Here is the link to [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Comment: Note that "Multiply them all" carries the argument, but I'm not sure how exactly you're using it.  It seems like you're either using "$p \nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$ implies $p\nmid ab$" (i.e. Euclid's lemma in disguise) or you're using "$\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c)\cdot\gcd(b,c)$" (coincidentally, I can't think of a proof of this at the moment that doesn't use the sledgehammer of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).  Can you clarify?

Comment: I think this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492022/does-gcda-bc-divides-gcda-b-gcda-c#:~:text=%28gcd%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%E2%8B%85%20gcd%20%28a%2C%20c%29%29%20Z,%E2%88%A3%20gcd%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%E2%8B%85%20gcd%20%28a%2C%20c%29.) can help you.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I had actually written out that same expression and yet missed the conclusion.  The tools then that underpin that are just the extended Euclidean algorithm.  Also, I take it by your responding indirectly with that link that you were using the form given by $\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c)\cdot \gcd(b,c)$.

Comment: I see. I edited this step into my answer.

Comment: @Itoz I couldn't understand the step where you're "multiplying them all"

Comment: This is because "gcd(ab,c)∣gcd(a,c)⋅gcd(b,c)", and we can use it repeatly. By the way, by using Euclid's lemma, we have "p∤a and p∤b implies  p∤ab", we can also solve this problem.

Comment: @Brian Integers coprime to $p$ are closed under product - seer the linked dupe.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Bill I'm well-aware of this theorem, but seeing a linked dupe tells me nothing about how someone else's argument goes.  Perhaps you're also mostly responding to my parenthetical brain-fart in my first comment, but that should have been considered secondary to my point of clarification.